# find the formal solution of wave equation

Tags: wave-equation

$$\begin{align} &\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u = \alpha^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},\qquad && 0<x<L,\qquad t>0\\
&u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0, && t>0\\[2ex]
&u(x,0) = f(x), &&0<x<L\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0) = 0, && 0<x<L
\end{align}
$$

I need to derive the formal solution.

I used the method of separation of variables.
What I did so far is:

Let $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ and get :
$$
\begin{cases}
X'' = \lambda X\\
T''+T'+T = \alpha^2\lambda T
\end{cases}
$$

I found that $X(x) = Csin\frac{n\pi x}L$, but having trouble find T(t).

$$\begin{align}T''+T'+T &= \alpha^2\lambda T \\
 T''+T'+(1 - \alpha^2\lambda)T &= 0\\
r^2+r +(1 - \alpha^2\lambda) & =0\\[2ex]
r = -\frac12 \pm &\frac{\sqrt{1-4(1 - \alpha^2\lambda)}}2\\
r_n = r + \frac12\\[2ex]
\text{and finally get:}\\
 T(t) = C_1 e^{-\frac t2}cos(r_nt) &+C_2 e^{-\frac t2}sin(r_nt)
\end{align}
$$

Is it correct?

Does $T(t)$ has to satisfy  $T'(0)=0$?